# How to publish HTML files online

Tags: html, css, jobs

I have a bunch of `HTML` files that I’ve created for websites.

But my question is how do I get them online or for people to see them? I want to start applying to jobs but nobody can see my work, they're just on my desktop.

Comment: Have you searched?

Comment: Any non-dark-web storage site will do. Maybe your ISP can provide you with a hosting site. What features does it give you? Home page?

Answer (score 1):

You could host your code in GitHub.
Simply sign up, create a new repository per project and push your code up.
Here is a great getting started tutorial for that: https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Answer (score 0):

Are they raw HTML and CSS files? You will need to FTP them into your host. Filezilla is a great FTP client and you can snag that here:

https://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Purchase some hosting space or for temporary you can get some free hosting account and then use File Manager inside CPanel or use Filezilla, upload your files and check it live. You will need to connect to some domain to your hosting space.

Answer (score 0):

For static websites:

1. Netlify - https://www.netlify.com
2. Github pages - https://pages.github.com

Or you can google "free webhosting"